# zmq_ctx_destroy() hangs in MFC dll

Tags: c++, sockets, dll, mfc, zeromq

I'm writing an extension to MFC app with use of ZMQ (zmq.hpp). When I'm trying to unload my DLL from the app, the zmq_ctx_destroy() function hangs forever.

I have found [a similar issue](http://grokbase.com/t/zeromq/zeromq-dev/12cke9ffpc/zmq-ctx-destroy-stocks-forever-when-statically-built-on-windows) but there is no answer.

I've tried to debug it and found out that it stops in function zmq::thread_t::stop() on the first line:

```
DWORD rc = WaitForSingleObject (descriptor, INFINITE);
```

It hung even without sending anything. Simplified code looks like this:

```
zmq::context_t context(1);
zmq::socket_t socket(context, ZMQ_REQ);
socket.connect(ENDPOINT.c_str());
```

Socket and context destroyed when leaving scope.

Call Stack:

```
libzmq-v100-mt-gd-4_0_4.dll! zmq::thread_t::stop()  Line 56 + 0x17 bytes    C++ 
libzmq-v100-mt-gd-4_0_4.dll! zmq::select_t::~select_t()  Line 57 + 0x13 bytes   C++ 
libzmq-v100-mt-gd-4_0_4.dll! zmq::select_t::`scalar deleting destructor'()  + 0x2c bytes    C++
libzmq-v100-mt-gd-4_0_4.dll! zmq::io_thread_t::~io_thread_t()  Line 39 + 0x37 bytes C++
libzmq-v100-mt-gd-4_0_4.dll! zmq::io_thread_t::`scalar deleting destructor'()  + 0x2c bytes C++
libzmq-v100-mt-gd-4_0_4.dll! zmq::ctx_t::~ctx_t()  Line 82 + 0x49 bytes C++
libzmq-v100-mt-gd-4_0_4.dll! zmq::ctx_t::`scalar deleting destructor'()  + 0x2c bytes   C++
libzmq-v100-mt-gd-4_0_4.dll! zmq::ctx_t::terminate()  Line 153 + 0x3d bytes C++
libzmq-v100-mt-gd-4_0_4.dll! zmq_ctx_term(void * ctx_)  Line 171 + 0xa bytes    C++
libzmq-v100-mt-gd-4_0_4.dll! zmq_ctx_destroy(void * ctx_)  Line 242 C++
DataReader.dll! zmq::context_t::close()  Line 309 + 0xe bytes   C++
DataReader.dll! zmq::context_t::~context_t()  Line 303  C++
```

The MFC app has a mechanism to run specifically created DLLs. This DLL is based on CWinApp, all DLL-specific initialization code in the InitInstance member function and termination code in ExitInstance. So [this JIRA issue](https://zeromq.jira.com/browse/LIBZMQ-538) should not be the case.

After a couple of days I found out that the app also relies on sockets as ZMQ. So at the end of its life ZMQ context was waiting for closing of all opened sockets in the process, but MFC app continues to use its opened sockets. That was the reason why zmq_ctx_destroy() function hangs forever.

Comment: That's a bug report for ZMQ or MFC not a question for SO, IMHO. Anyhow, sources for both are available, so feel free to debug the problem. I think that ZMQ uses a few globals, those are the ones I would take a look at, they caused issues in other environments as well.

Comment: [DllMain entry point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583.aspx): *"**Warning**  There are significant limits on what you can safely do in a DLL entry point. See [General Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971.aspx#general_best_practices) for specific Windows APIs that are unsafe to call in DllMain."*

Answer (score -1):

Solution for cases like this one (when app uses sockets as well and you need to add some functionality based on ZMQ).
Create a new process. This process will create a ZMQ context and send/receive all messages. Data from dll could be passed to that process via Windows messages or shared memory.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Why this does not provide an answer to the question?

Comment: It reads like a comment, or an extension to your own question. It might be clear to you and if so accept it, but it either looks like you were initially doing  it wrong, or this is a work around. Think about a future SO user .

Comment: So, should I delete my answer? I have made some changes in the question and answer.

Comment: No mate. It got thrown at me as a reviewer, and I had some issues with it, so did Craig S Anderson. You've improved it enough that my objection is going to look out of date, so it's unlikely that other future reviewers are going to vote for a delete. Takes more than two of us, otherwise it would already be gone. Even then you have the chance to square it up and reviewers get a re-open request.

Comment: I'm a future SO user... I've got an app with `zmq_ctx_destroy()` hanging and no clue what you're talking about in this answer.  Perhaps you mean to refer to a separate thread instead of separate process?

Comment: @ebyrob I've made it more clear - my solution was to move ZMQ to separate process (not thread).

Comment: @trgroup Thanks, that's much more clear.  Wow, using inter-process communication on top of ZMQ seems like a major pain though when ZMQ is supposed to solve inter-process communication for you.

Comment: @ebyrob You've totally defeated the entire purpose of ZMQ, which is to provide interprocess communication.